# How to do something 'on success' in an Async Function using Try and Catch?

Tags: javascript, async-await

I have an async function that posts data to Firebase Firestore. It works, apart from I need it to do some things after the data has been posted, or 'on success'.

In the code below I'm trying to 'setLoading' to false after the data has been posted to Firestore. The data does get posted, but the loading value remains true. Can anyone see what is wrong with my code, please? I want to do some other things apart from change the value of 'loading', but I'm just using this one instance as an example here.

```
async function uploadData(e) {

    e.preventDefault()

    try {
        setLoading(true)
        return await useFireStore
            ...
    }

    catch {
        setError('Post failed')
    }

    setLoading(false)  // this isn't working

}
```

Cheers, Matt

Comment: Do `useFireStore.then(...)` if I understand you need to use promises.

Comment: @MindaugasNakrosis - There's no reason to use `.then` above. It's an `async` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you're using `return` in your `try` catch. This is no different from when you're using `try`/`catch` and `return` in a non-`async` function. (By design.)

Typically you'd use `finally` for this:

```
async function uploadData(e) {

    e.preventDefault()

    try {
        setLoading(true)
        return await useFireStore/*...*/;
    }
    catch {
        setError('Post failed')
    }
    finally {
        setLoading(false)  // this isn't working
    }
}
```

Note that the `await` in the above is important. There's no need for `return await somePromise` if it's at the top level of your function code (just use `return somePromise`), but the `await` can make a big difference if it's not at the top level, which is the case here. So you **do** need that `await`.

---

Side note: As written, your function fulfills its promise with the result of the `useFireStore` call if it works, but with `undefined` if it doesn't work. If `useFireStore` can return `undefined`, that means code using your function has no idea whether the operation succeeded or failed. (But if `useFireStore` doesn't every return `undefined` on success, then code using your function could tell the difference.)

Comment: Fantastic, thank you T.J. The solution worked perfectly, and your answer explained to me why it worked. Sincere thanks. Have a great day

Answer (score 2):

If you want something to happen on success, you just place is below your `await`. If you want it to happen no matter what, you can use the `finally` block.

```
try {
  setLoading(true)
  const result = await useFireStore;

  // logic here to run on success

  return result;
}
catch {
  setError('Post failed')
}
finally{
  // logic here to always run

  setLoading(false); 
}
```

Comment: Cheers Todd, you're right, I was missing the 'finally'. Thanks, Matt

Answer (score 1):

You used `return` inside `try` block so it is returning without setting the loading status to false. Also, you should set the loading status to false on error case as well, so your code should look like:

```js
async function uploadData(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    
    setLoading(true)
    
    try {
        await useFireStore
    }
    catch {
        setError('Post failed')
    }
    finally {
        setLoading(false)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Thunder, you're right, I was missing the 'finally'. Cheers, Matt

Answer (score 1):

You're returning after the request is created, if you need to use the response, store it in the variable instead of returning, also if you want to make sure any code is executed after the request was completed ( successful or unsuccessful), use the finally block

```
async function uploadData(e) {

  e.preventDefault()

  try {
    setLoading(true)
    const response = await useFireStore(); // don't return here
    // use the response var if it request returns any data 
  } catch {
    setError('Post failed')
  } finally {
    setLoading(false) //move the setLoading here    
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Ashu, you're right, I was missing the 'finally'. Cheers, Matt